# Finding the maximum of this function using a continuous approximation of factorials

Tags: derivatives, graph-theory, maxima-minima, gamma-function, network

I have this function I'm trying to find the maximum of by using Stirling's approximation for factorials

$$
\frac{{N \choose 2}!}{m! \left( {N \choose 2} - m \right)!} \approx \frac{\Gamma({N \choose 2}+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma({N \choose 2}-m+1)}
$$

where
$$
\Gamma'(m+1) =  m!\left( - \gamma \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k}  \right)
$$
for positive integers

My problem is when I calculate the derivative I get a messy equation that I'm having trouble solving. Is there a better way to cancel out this function or take the derivative?

Comment: Maximum as a function of what? Is $N$ fixed and you’re trying to maximize in $m$? Then the maximum occurs when $m$ is half of ${N \choose 2}$ (rounded) and you don’t need to know anything about derivatives or Gamma functions to prove it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, sorry, I am trying to maximize m. What technique would you use to go about proving this? I was given a hint to use the gamma function but it may have thrown me off more than it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you don't need to know anything about derivatives or Gamma functions or even Stirling's approximation to do this. The following is totally elementary:

> **Proposition:** For fixed $N$, the function ${N \choose m}$ is maximized when $m = \left\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \right\rfloor$.

*Proof.* We just calculate that

$$\frac{ {N \choose m+1} }{ {N \choose m} } = \frac{m!(N-m)!}{(m+1)!(N-(m+1))!} = \frac{N - m}{m+1}.$$

From this it follows immediately that ${N \choose m+1} \ge {N \choose m}$ if and only if $\frac{N - m}{m + 1} \ge 1$ if and only if $N \ge 2m+1$, and similarly for strict inequalities. This gives that the function $m \mapsto {N \choose m}$ is strictly increasing for $0 \le m \le \frac{N-2}{2}$ and strictly decreasing for $\frac{N}{2} \le m \le N$.

If $N$ is even we get that the maximum occurs when $m = \frac{N}{2}$ and if $N$ is odd we get that the maximum occurs at both $m = \left\lfloor \frac{N}{2} \right\rfloor$ and $m = \left\lceil \frac{N}{2} \right\rceil$. $\Box$

Heuristically this happens because by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) approaches a normal distribution centered at its mean, which is $\frac{N}{2}$. It may help to stare at a graph of the probability mass function of a binomial distribution, which is given at the Wikipedia article. The above calculation can be adapted to finding the maximum of ${N \choose m} p^m (1 - p)^{N-m}$ as well (a binomial distribution with parameter $p$, corresponding to $N$ flips of a coin with bias $p$), which as expected occurs near the mean $Np$.